# How do I count the instances of a keyword in SQL Text

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table containing rows and one of the columns is of type `text` storing Json. I want to count how many Json data items there are (I want to count the instances of a string 'aodata.id" in each) and store that number in a column of type `int` called `JsonRowsInThis`.

I tried to select like this

```
SELECT 
    value  
FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT((select top 1 MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent from RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems), 'odata.id')
```

but I am using SQL Server 2014 and `string_split` does not work for it.

Is there a solution to count the number of a character using replace but it did not work for my case?

A sample of the content of a cell below (partial content, it is very long)

```
{"@odata.context":"https://mywebsite.com/$metadata#Media","value":[{"@odata.id":"https://mywebsite.com/Media('5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8f7')","MediaKey":"5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8f7","ImageWidth":290,"ImageHeight":218,"ImageSizeDescription":"290x218","MediaURL":"https://s3.Cloudserver24.com/mlsgrid/images/eb726144-0302-4f04-a1b1-554b8a476ba3.jpeg","Modified":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z","ModificationTimestamp":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z","ResourceRecordKey":"CAR28791079","ResourceRecordID":"CARNCM530248","ResourceName":"property","OriginatingSystemName":"carolina","MlgCanView":true,"Order":"0"},{"@odata.id":"https://mywebsite.com/Media('5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8fa')","MediaKey":"5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8fa","ImageWidth":290,"ImageHeight":218,"ImageSizeDescription":"290x218","MediaURL":"https://s3.Cloudserver24.com/mlsgrid/images/82120215-cf3c-44b2-9786-cadd60d68db0.jpeg","Modified":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z","ModificationTimestamp":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z","ResourceRecordKey":"CAR28791079","ResourceRecordID":"CARNCM530248","ResourceName":"property","OriginatingSystemName":"carolina","MlgCanView":true,"Order":"3"},{"@odata.id":"https://mywebsite.com/Media('5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8f8')","MediaKey":"5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8f8","ImageWidth":290,"ImageHeight":218,"ImageSizeDescription":"290x218","MediaURL":"https://s3.Cloudserver24.com/mlsgrid/images/641b2e26-f022-44af-bfbf-c482df6a873c.jpeg","Modified":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z","ModificationTimestamp":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z","ResourceRecordKey":"CAR28791079","ResourceRecordID":"CARNCM530248","ResourceName":"property","OriginatingSystemName":"carolina","MlgCanView":true,"Order":"1"},{"@odata.id":"https://mywebsite.com/Media('5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a903')","MediaKey":"5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a903","ImageWidth":290,"ImageHeight":218,"ImageSizeDescription":"290x218","MediaURL":"https://s3.Cloudserver24.com/mlsgrid/images/066c658b-ede7-4f90-9cae-ef71774bc152.jpeg","Modified":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z","ModificationTimestamp":"2019-02- etc ......}
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can count the values like this:

```
select ( len(value) - len(replace(value, 'aodata.id')) ) / len('aodata.id) as num_aodata_id
```

EDIT:

You should not be using the `text` data type.  You can solve this by converting to `varchar(max)`:

```
select ( len(v.val) - len(replace(v.val, 'aodata.id')) ) / len('aodata.id) as num_aodata_id
from t cross apply
     (values (convert(varchar(max), t.value)) v(val)
```

Comment: I am confused, where do i replace with the name of the column MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent   please

Comment: when  I run it, the replace function gives an error (required 3 arguments)..
Sql server management studio

my applied code to run it is 

select top 13 ( len([RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems]) - len(replace([RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems], 'adata.id')) ) / len('odata.id) as num_aodata_id,
[MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id]
from [RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems]
(multiple errors)

Comment: Will these commands like `LEN` and `REPLACE` work against a column of type `TEXT`?? I remember this being a really annoyingly difficult datatype to work with, since most of the "usual" string functions couldn't be used with that data type...

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive `cte` as substitute for `string_split` function.

```
;with cte as (
    select 0 as ctr, charindex('odata.id', MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent ) as pos
        , MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent  as strdata 
    from RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems
    union all
    select ctr + 1, charindex('odata.id', strdata , pos + 1), strdata
    from cte
    where pos > 0
)
select count(1) from cte where pos > 0
```

Comment: If I want to run the update on the top 10 rows, (there is a lot of data), please how to I do that?

Comment: I  modified it but :(

with cte as (
    select 0 as ctr, charindex('odata', MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent ) as pos
        , MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent  as strdata ,MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id
    from RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems
    union all
    select ctr + 1, charindex('odata', strdata , pos + 1), strdata,MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id
    from cte
    where pos > 0
)
select top 1000  count(1),MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id from cte where pos > 0 group by   
MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id
order by MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id desc 

it gave inaccurate results

Comment: `Update  t1
 from RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems t1
 set t1.1 = update_column
 inner join 
  (select top 1000 MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id from cte where pos > 0 group by MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id order by MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id desc) t2 
  on t2.MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id = t1.MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id`

Comment: hi,
still giving error. 

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 68
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 7, Line 68
't1' is not a recognized SET option.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 68
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Comment: this is the basic of the create table that can replicate the issue
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems](
 [MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
 [MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent] [text] NULL 
 [MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_AodataIdCount] [int] NULL 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help if you can use SQL Server 2016 or higher. The data in your column is a valid `JSON`, so instead of using string based approach (based on `STRING_SPLIT()`), you may try to use `JSON` functions.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "@odata.context":"https://mywebsite.com/$metadata#Media",
   "value":[
      {
         "@odata.id":"https://mywebsite.com/Media(''5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8f7'')",
         "MediaKey":"5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8f7",
         "ImageWidth":290,
         "ImageHeight":218,
         "ImageSizeDescription":"290x218",
         "MediaURL":"https://s3.Cloudserver24.com/mlsgrid/images/eb726144-0302-4f04-a1b1-554b8a476ba3.jpeg",
         "Modified":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z",
         "ModificationTimestamp":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z",
         "ResourceRecordKey":"CAR28791079",
         "ResourceRecordID":"CARNCM530248",
         "ResourceName":"property",
         "OriginatingSystemName":"carolina",
         "MlgCanView":true,
         "Order":"0"
      },
      {
         "@odata.id":"https://mywebsite.com/Media(''5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8fa'')",
         "MediaKey":"5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8fa",
         "ImageWidth":290,
         "ImageHeight":218,
         "ImageSizeDescription":"290x218",
         "MediaURL":"https://s3.Cloudserver24.com/mlsgrid/images/82120215-cf3c-44b2-9786-cadd60d68db0.jpeg",
         "Modified":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z",
         "ModificationTimestamp":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z",
         "ResourceRecordKey":"CAR28791079",
         "ResourceRecordID":"CARNCM530248",
         "ResourceName":"property",
         "OriginatingSystemName":"carolina",
         "MlgCanView":true,
         "Order":"3"
      },
      {
         "@odata.id":"https://mywebsite.com/Media(''5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8f8'')",
         "MediaKey":"5b9f36ec5928d64cdb53a8f8",
         "ImageWidth":290,
         "ImageHeight":218,
         "ImageSizeDescription":"290x218",
         "MediaURL":"https://s3.Cloudserver24.com/mlsgrid/images/641b2e26-f022-44af-bfbf-c482df6a873c.jpeg",
         "Modified":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z",
         "ModificationTimestamp":"2019-02-03T11:18:18.300Z",
         "ResourceRecordKey":"CAR28791079",
         "ResourceRecordID":"CARNCM530248",
         "ResourceName":"property",
         "OriginatingSystemName":"carolina",
         "MlgCanView":true,
         "Order":"1"
      }
   ]
}'
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems (
   MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent text
)
INSERT INTO RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems (MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent)
VALUES (@json), (@json)
```

Statement (count all items in the `JSON` column):

```
SELECT 
   r.MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id,
   Cnt = (
         SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM OPENJSON(r.MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent, '$.value')
         )
FROM RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems r
```

Statement (count all items in the `JSON` column, which have `"@odata.id"` key):

```
SELECT 
   r.MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_Id,
   Cnt = (
         SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM OPENJSON(r.MLSImportedGroupsOfItems_ImportedContent, '$.value')
         WITH ([@odata.id] nvarchar(100) '$."@odata.id"')
         WHERE [@odata.id] IS NOT NULL
         )
FROM RE_MLSImportedGroupsOfItems r
```